# Eclipseの色設定が分からない

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse 2019-09 R (4.13.0) を使用しています。
添付画像の、背景色が白（とても薄いグレー）になっている部分の色を変えたいのですが、どの項目で変えられるのか分かりません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どうやら、以下の条件が揃うとこの色になるようです：

1. リストの項目
2. 選択している
3. フォーカスしていない（Eclipseの他の部分にフォーカスしている）

ただ、全てのリストがこうなるわけではないみたいですが・・・
白だと非常に見辛いので変えたいです。
下の画像の入力補完の方は、渋々文字色を変えて対処しています・・・

Comment: 標準の設定項目には存在しないように見えます(自分の好みに合うテーマを探してそれを適用するのが手っ取り早そうです): https://stackoverflow.com/q/3866471/4506703